# Conflict with blank character in R

Tags: linux, r

I am running the following command on my text data string in R...

```
data$income_val_b <- ifelse(data$annualincome_b == '£20k to 30k' , 11,data$income_val_b)
```

and...

```
data$income_val_b <- ifelse(data$annualincome_b == '£20k to 30k' , 11,data$income_val_b)
```

While both look the same the space character in the two is different. When checked in excel using =code() command the first text shows space as character 32 while the second shows it as character 160.

While these two commands work fine when I use my R on a windows platform, the second command with space as character 160 throws an error in R when I run it on Linux platform:

> Invalid multibyte character in parser in line 1

I really need my algo to run in Linux entirely. Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure why U+00A0 would fail on Linux; Unicode characters should work fine in R code (and it sounds like U+00A3 `£` is working for you on Linux). What's the error message?

Comment: Though a little more verbose, can you use `ifelse( grepl("£20k\\sto\\s30k", data$annualincome_b), ..., ...)`?

Comment: I was going to suggest using `intToUtf8(160)` to avoid having to hard-code the U+00A0, but honestly, you shouldn't have to do that, Unicode characters should work in R code.

Comment: It says "invalid character in first line"... Also yes it seems I have a problem with £ character too. When i remove both £ and char 160 from the text it works...

Comment: actually the '£20k to 30k' is a part of the data which gets extracted from the server. I need to able able to convert this in Linux somehow...

Comment: Sorry the exact error message is "Invalid multibyte character in parser in line 1"

Comment: I think this would go a long way if you included a reproducible example.

Comment: Here's the example...

When i run the following script in R on windows...

`a <- " "` ... 
`a1 <- ifelse(a == " ",1,0)` ... 
`a1` ... 

I get the output as 1. Here the character is non-break space.

When i run the same in Linux using Rscript "filename" command the following error appears...

`[root@linux40 ~]# Rscript (filename)` 
`Error: invalid multibyte character in parser at line 1` 
`Execution halted`

Comment: The same is the case when is use £ instead of non-break space